# Retrieving XmlDocument class object from .net web service in Android

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap

I have to get xml data from a .net web service. The webservice returns an XMLDocument object. I have been unable to successfully retrive/interpret the data as XML with start tags etc. It looks like this

MethodResponse{MethodResult=anyType{BUILDINGPERMITS=anyType{PERMITS=anyType{APNO=     1829; YCOORD=36.09593993; XCOORD=-80.24505836; JOBADDRESS=200 W SECOND ST WINSTON-SALEM 27101-; STATUS=Closed; }; ...

I can succssfully retrieve XML data if it is sent as a string rather than XMLDocument.
Is there a way to get XML data from a webservice that returns a .net object like XMLDocument or is that just not practical?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be better off retrieving the xml data as a String.  See [working with xml in android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/) for a variety of ways of dealing with xml data.